# Solaris LDOM operating system space?

Tags: solaris

How much OS space is required to create a Solaris LDOM on a Physical server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An LDOM requires a minimum of one core, plus software.  More can be allocated. You can have up 64 LDOMS onn one physical box.

You can then create zones inside each LDOM.

Beyond that - your question is so general you should read about this stuff before you ask more:

http://www.developers.net/sunicshowcase/view/2708

Comment: Two small corrections: An LDOM requires one thread, not one core. Also, you can have up to 128 LDOMs on one physical box with a T5440.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for reply. Core allocation etc. is fine. Yes, it is a general query that, if I have one phsyical server eg. Sun T5240 on which I intened to create 5 LDOMS ,the server is having 300 GB disk space. Can we assign 60 GB to each LDOM for OS and application space or there is another way out? please forgive me for little understanding.